# Replace Image in ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, imagelist

I encountered a problem as I wrote on title.

I use ListView for File Explorer, and there's lots of image files.

the problem which I need to solve occurred when I replace image file with same name.

**Question :**

- I wish to replace Image which has specific ImageKey in ImageList.
- To do this, I Remove Image in ImageList with ImageKey. After that, I tried to add Image with that ImageKey.

**Note :**

- I use 'File Location' as ImageKey
- I Remove ImageKey in ImageList for replace Image in list.
- After I tried to add new image in ImageList (with same Key) it doesn't inserted.
- AddImageKey is well wowrked function which I use everywhere.

  - it returns String for 'ImageKey' value.

    - if file is not an image, it returns it's extension ( ex : .exe )
    - if key target is directory, it returns < DIR >
- il16, il32, il32FullSize is ImageList

**My Code with Error :**

```
il16.Images.RemoveByKey( fi.FullName );
il32.Images.RemoveByKey( fi.FullName );
il32FullSize.Images.RemoveByKey( fi.FullName );

item.ImageKey = AddImageKey( fi.FullName, false );
```

**Well Worked My AddImageKey Function :**

```
public String AddImageKey( String Location, bool IsDirectory, bool UseDefault = false )
{
    String Retval = "";
    if ( IsDirectory )
    {
        Retval = "<DIR>";
        if ( !AddedExtensions.Contains( Retval ) )
        {
            Icon img = this.win32.GetIcon( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(), true );
            il16.Images.Add( Retval, img );
            img = this.win32.GetIcon( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(), false );
            il32.Images.Add( Retval, img );
            img = this.win32.GetIcon( Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString(), false );
            il32FullSize.Images.Add( Retval, img );
             AddedExtensions.Add( Retval );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo( Location );
        try
        {
            if ( UseDefault )
            {
                throw new Exception("Use Default Icon");
            }
            if ( !AddedImages.Contains( fi.FullName ) )
            {
                Image img = Image.FromFile( fi.FullName );
                il16.Images.Add( fi.FullName, img.GetThumbnailImage( 16, 16, null, new IntPtr()) );
                il32.Images.Add( fi.FullName, img.GetThumbnailImage( 128, 128, null, new IntPtr() ) );
                il32FullSize.Images.Add( fi.FullName, img.GetThumbnailImage( 128, 128, null, new IntPtr() ) );
                img.Dispose();
                AddedImages.Add( fi.FullName );
            }
            Retval = fi.FullName;
        }
        catch
        {
            if ( !AddedExtensions.Contains( fi.Extension ) )
            {
                Icon img = this.win32.GetIcon( fi.FullName, true );
                il16.Images.Add( GetExt( fi.FullName ), img );
                img = this.win32.GetIcon( fi.FullName, false );
                il32.Images.Add( GetExt( fi.FullName ), img );
                il32FullSize.Images.Add( GetExt( fi.FullName ), img );
                AddedExtensions.Add( fi.Extension );
            }
            Retval = fi.Extension;
        }
    }
    return Retval;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε The problem which I encountered is if I use this code, Image ( which key is fi.FullName ) is not listed on il16, il32, il32Fullsize ( Existing ImageLists ) even AddImageKey Function already executed.

Comment: I dont think that it is a code issue. You need to debug your code line by line: are the images removed prior `AddImageKey`? do the images you add exist? is the file path correct?

Comment: As i see now you are adding `128x128` image in `il32` which holds `32x32` images: `il32.Images.Add( fi.FullName, img.GetThumbnailImage( 128, 128, null, new IntPtr() ) );`

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε it is 32 bit image list. it does not hold only 32x32 images. anyways, when I tried it, images automatically converted it's size.
As I wrote, AddImageKey is well worked.

Comment: Ok then. If *AddImageKey is well worked* then why these images are not being add in your list. Either it works well and the images are added or not and they are not. Choose one. You can not have both!

Comment: Key and Index are not the same. You need to insert at the same inxed and with the same key if you want the imagelist to stay in snych for all cases!#